# How can I show 3D movement plus time in a plot?

Tags: data-visualization

I have a visualization of trajectories in 3D (movement within a building). Is there any visualization for plotting 3D movement plus time?

Comment: Maybe color your trajectory along the way?

Comment: This seems to request a 3D parametric, smoothly connected point, list-plot with time as the parameter demarcated with points labled at their times of occurance.